# Xamarin using MSAL Azure B2C for authentication, sends headers with sensitive details in aquire token request and credentials without encrypting it

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, azure-ad-msal

I am using MSAL library for authentication in my Xamarin.Forms app, it is working fine but while penn testing, it was revealing too much details like below

```
x-client-SKU: MSAL.Xamarin.Android
x-client-Ver: 4.4.0.0
x-client-DM: Redmi ***
```

This also we could see credentials in plain string see this in [image: screenshot]

My question is, is there a way to hide or omit or encrypt these extra params and credentials while making request.

One way is to intercept these request using [NetBare](http://%20%20https://github.com/MegatronKing/NetBare) library and remove these headers, but this is a challenge on its own.

below code :

```
AuthenticationClient = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(MyClientId)
    .WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup(MyKeychainSecurityGroups)
    .WithB2CAuthority(MyAuthoritySignin)
    .Build();

var result = await AuthenticationClient
    .AcquireTokenInteractive(MyScopes)
    .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
    .WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true)
    .WithParentActivityOrWindow(App.UIParent)
    .ExecuteAsync()
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Does it operate under HTTPS?

Comment: yes, our azure b2c endpoint is https, still we can clearly see headers.